# How to remove object from NSMutableArray that hasSufix

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray

I have a NSMutableArray created like this..

```
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"http://192.168.43.1:8080/mediaListFull"];
    NSURL *stringURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:stringURL];
    NSString *stringFromData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


/// Populating the urlArray "tableView" from stringFromData..
    urlArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    urlArray = [[stringFromData componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]mutableCopy];
```

I want to remove all strings that have suffix .jpg I am using this code to try to accomplish this but it is not working.

```
 NSString *stringToRemove = @".jpg";
for (int i = 0; i < urlArray.count; i ++) {
     NSLog(@"The UrlArray has this in it %@",[urlArray objectAtIndex:i]);
    NSString *temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[urlArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    if ([temp hasSuffix:stringToRemove]) {
        [urlArray removeObjectAtIndex:i];
    }

}
```

So when i log the array it still has all of the .jpg files in it. 
Any help much appreciated.

```
FYI the array looks like this.
```

2016-07-28 10:00:22.087 ImageURLDownLoad[716:232095] The urlArray has this in it (

```
 "http://192.168.43.1:8080/mediaResponse/?fileName=/storage/emulated/0/liveMedia/LivePic-19700101_001527.jpg
",
    "http://192.168.43.1:8080/mediaResponse/?fileName=/storage/emulated/0/liveMedia/LivePic-19700101_001533.jpg
",
    "http://192.168.43.1:8080/mediaResponse/?fileName=/storage/emulated/0/liveMedia/LivePic-19700101_000600.jpg
",
    "http://192.168.43.1:8080/mediaResponse/?fileName=/storage/emulated/0/liveMedia/LivePic-19700101_000605.jpg
",
    "http://192.168.43.1:8080/mediaResponse/?fileName=/storage/emulated/0/liveMedia/LivePic-19700101_000610.jpg
",
    "http://192.168.43.1:8080/mediaResponse/?fileName=/storage/emulated/0/liveMedia/LivePic-19700101_000632.jpg
",
    "http://192.168.43.1:8080/mediaResponse/?fileName=/storage/emulated/0/liveMedia/LivePic-19700101_000642.jpg
",
    "http://192.168.43.1:8080/mediaResponse/?fileName=/storage/emulated/0/liveMedia/LivePic-19700101_000652.jpg
",
    "http://192.168.43.1:8080/mediaResponse/?fileName=/storage/emulated/0/liveMedia/LiveVid-19700101_000544.mp4
",
    "http://192.168.43.1:8080/mediaResponse/?fileName=/storage/emulated/0/liveMedia/LiveVid-19700101_001101.mp4
",
    "http://192.168.43.1:8080/mediaResponse/?fileName=/storage/emulated/0/liveMedia/LiveVid-19700101_001129.mp4
",
    "http://192.168.43.1:8080/mediaResponse/?fileName=/storage/emulated/0/liveMedia/LiveVid-19700101_001429.mp4
",
    "http://192.168.43.1:8080/mediaResponse/?fileName=/storage/emulated/0/liveMedia/LivePic-19700101_004538.mp4"
)
```

Regards
JZ

Comment: `[urlArray filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF ENDSWITH[c] %@", @".jpg"]`? And the alloc/init of `urlArray` is useless since you assign it just afterwards.

Comment: I tried this "[urlArray filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF ENDSWITH[c] %@", @".jpg"]" , It removes all of the contents of the array.

Comment: It's because it seems there is an extra char at the end of each URL. And I made the predicate to keep only the on with .jpg, it should have a NOT before.

Answer (score 1):

There is generally, in any language/library, issues relating to looping through an array and modifying the array within that loop. In Objective-C, this manifests as a `Collection XXX was mutated while being enumerated` exception.  I am surprised you are not getting this exception (it probably means your test is failing and no attempt is being made to remove an entry from the array).

(**EDIT** I believe your URL strings have an extraneous newline at the end, which is why you haven't hit this exception).

There are a couple of accepted workarounds:

1. Iterate backwards through the array.
2. Keep a list of entries to remove and remove them, en masse, at the end.

I normally use the latter method:

```
NSMutableArray *toRemove = [NSMutableArray new];
for (NSString *url in urlArray)
    if ([url hasSuffix:stringToRemove])
        [toRemove addObject:url];
[urlArray removeObjectsInArray:toRemove];
```

Comment: I also tried this  NSMutableArray *toRemove = [NSMutableArray new];
for (NSString *url in urlArray)
    if ([url hasSuffix:stringToRemove)
        [toRemove addObject:url];
[urlArray removeObjectsInArray:toRemove];  Without success

Comment: Thank you very much , will try different versions of each.

Comment: I see it now, I also tried to add a @".jpg\n" I am still not hitting the exception. hmmmmmm ... :(

Comment: @JohnZ It might not be a newline at the end of the string.  You need to debug this with a breakpoint and look at one of the strings being added to the array.

Comment: Okay !! Great ,,, 100 % correct the URL string did have a "/r" not a "/n" so thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I gave you an up vote now my urlArray only has my .mp4 files in it ... :)))  Thank you all for the help. JZ